# Validate Order against XSD in Camel

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, apache-camel

I'm trying to validate an incoming request-order (xml format) against an XSD using a Camel route configuration. However I keep getting the error below. Can anyone help, my code is below.

```
@Override
public void configure() {

//Other code

 onException(ValidationException.class)
            .to("{{jms.queue.invalidRequestQueue}}");

       from("{{jms.queue.fulfilmentRequest}}")
        .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
            .to("validation:src/main/resources/xml/OrderCanonical.xsd", "{{jms.queue.fulfilmentRequest}}")
        .transacted(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED)
            .setHeader(ORDER_ID, xpath(XPATH_FOR_ORDERLINE).namespaces(nm).stringResult())
            .beanRef("indiciaService", "getIndicias")
            .choice()
                .when(header(BOLPMessageHeaders.STATUS).isEqualTo(BOLPFulfilmentStatuses.FAILED))
                    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "Indicia call failed. Skipping call to Adobe.")
                    .to("{{jms.queue.fulfilmentResponse}}")
                .otherwise()
                    .beanRef("adobePostageService", "generatePdf")
                    .setHeader(BOLPMessageHeaders.STATUS, simple(BOLPFulfilmentStatuses.FULFILLED))
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, PRINT_HEADERS)
                    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, PRINT_BODY)
                    .to("{{jms.queue.fulfilmentResponse}}");
}
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route BOLPFulfilmentRoute at: >>> To[validator:src/main/resources/xml/OrderCanonical.xsd] <<< in route: Route(BOLPFulfilmentRoute)[[From[{{jms.queue.fulfilmentReque... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: validator://src/main/resources/xml/OrderCanonical.xsd due to: Cannot find resource: src/main/resources/xml/OrderCanonical.xsd in classpath for URI: src/main/resources/xml/OrderCanonical.xsd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it should be `validator` instead of `validation`, right?

According to the error message, the XSD file is not found. Please try following file path:

```
from("{{jms.queue.fulfilmentRequest}}")
    .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
    .to("validator:xml/OrderCanonical.xsd")
```

Comment: That worked great noob error :) Thanks a lot appreciate your help!

Comment: @dStudios Maybe you may accept the answer, so that it is obvious that the proplem is solved.